# Constructing a button during runtime

Tags: delphi

I have looked at the example but was unable to compile, due to the errors.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,Winapi.Messages,System.SysUtils,System.Variants,  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,     Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
editType: TEdit;
  private
{ Private declarations }
  public
{ Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;
  RunTimeButton : TButton;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

begin
  {Self refers to the form}
  RunTimeButton := TButton.Create(Self);
  {Assign properties now}
  RunTimeButton.Caption := 'Run-time';
  RunTimeButton.Left := 20;
  {Show the button}
  RunTimeButton.Visible := True;
end;

end.
```

The errors are :

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(28): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Self'
[dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(34): E2029 '.' expected but ';' found
```

Any idea how to fix it? I have looked up errors but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not declared a method for the code to execute inside. Find the `OnCreate` event for the form in the Object Inspector, double click it and put your code inside the event handler stub that the IDE generates.

You must also assign a `Parent` for the button. And it would be far better for the button to be a member of the form class.

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    editType: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FRunTimeButton: TButton;
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FRunTimeButton := TButton.Create(Self);
  FRunTimeButton.Parent := Self;
  FRunTimeButton.Caption := 'Run-time';
  FRunTimeButton.Left := 20;
end;
```

Comment: Shouldn't "You have declared" read "You have to declare" or similar?  In asking the q, the OP doesn't seem to realise that Delphi doesn't support a free-standing begin...end block within a unit, which is why, of course, he got the "'.' expected" error.

Comment: Actually, you can have a free standing begin-end block in the implementation section of a unit, but that is used for unit initialization. It should be at the end of the code, and have a full stop at its end. The OP doesn't quite seem to understand that TForm1 is a class and that code should generally be in methods. Newbies tend to think of the unit as the class and do not know that a form with code is just one of the many things you can declare in a unit.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:  Thank you, I know, but your comment expresses what I meant better than I did.